# Python matrix multiplication - result matrix size

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

I am trying to create the product matrix for matrix multiplication in Python, but I am not sure what size the matrix will be as the user can give any input for the matrix multiplication.

I've approached the situation using this for a previous task on matrices when the actual matrix size is provided
product_matrix = [[col for col in range(4)] for row in range(4)]

But I'm not sure how to tackle it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For `x = range(len(B[0]))`, did you mean `x = len(B[0])`?

By multiplying `A * B`, your resulting matrix `result` should have the `num_raw` of `A` and `num_col` of `B`.

`x = len(B[0])` means that your `x` is counting how many elements are there for each row of `B`, that is `x` is `num_col` of `B`. `len(A)` is counting how many rows are there in `A`, that is `len(A)` is `num_row` of `A`. Therefore, your `result` is initialized as "each row has `x` elements, and there are `len(A)` rows" with all entries of 0.

And the second line you provided should be in a for-loop, which is exactly the same how you calculate each entry of resulting matrix by hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
def inMatrix(m,n):#function For Multiplication  And Pass Row and col number as Parameter

    a=[]#Blank Matrix

    for i in range(m):#Row

        b=[]#Blank List

        for j in range(n):#col

            j=int(input("Enter Matrix Elements in pocket ["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]"))

            b.append(j)#add element to list

        a.append(b)#add List to Matrix

    return a #return Matrix

def priMatrix(a):#function for Print Matrix

    for i in range(len(a)): #row 

        for j in range(len(a[0])):#col

            print(a[i][j],end=" ") #print Number with space

        print()#print line for New row

def multply(a,b):#Multiplication function Pass two Matrix as Parameter

    mul=[] #Blank Matrix

    sum=0#sum With ) Value 

    for i in range(len(a)):#row

        l=[] #Blank list

        for j in range(len(a[0])):#col

            for k in range(len(b)):#select

                sum=sum+a[i][k]*b[k][j]#sum with Mul


            l.append(sum)#add Mul Value 

            sum=0#Sum 0 For Next Calculation

        mul.append(l)#Add List 

    return mul #return Multiplication Matrix 

m=int(input("row"))#First Matrix Row

n=int(input("col"))#First Matrix Col

a=inMatrix(m,n)#First Matrix input

j=int(input("row"))#second Matrix Row

k=int(input("col"))#second Matrix Col

b=inMatrix(j,k)#Second Matrix Input

priMatrix(a)#First Matrix Print 

priMatrix(b)#second Matrix Print 

c=multply(a,b)#Multiplication Matrix Function Call

priMatrix(c)#Multiplication Matrix Print
```